# django. Form creates blank objects for empty fields. How to prevent this/only create objects for populated fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have several models linked to a single form. The form creates and saves individual model objects.

Here are the models.

```
class Quarterback(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

     
class Runningback(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class Widereceiver(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class Tightend(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

            
class Kicker(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This is the form.

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):

    quarterback_name = forms.CharField(label='Quarterback', max_length=100, required=False)
    runningback_name = forms.CharField(label='Runningback', max_length=100, required=False)
    widereceiver_name = forms.CharField(label='Widereceiver', max_length=100, required=False)
    tightend_name = forms.CharField(label='Tightend', max_length=100, required=False)
    kicker_name = forms.CharField(label='Kicker', max_length=100, required=False)

    def save(self):
         quarterback_name = self.cleaned_data.get('quarterback_name')
         Quarterback.objects.create(name=quarterback_name)
         runningback_name = self.cleaned_data.get('runningback_name')
         Runningback.objects.create(name=runningback_name)
         widereceiver_name = self.cleaned_data.get('widereceiver_name')
         Widereceiver.objects.create(name=widereceiver_name)
         tightend_name = self.cleaned_data.get('tightend_name')
         Tightend.objects.create(name=tightend_name)
         kicker_name = self.cleaned_data.get('kicker_name')
         Kicker.objects.create(name=kicker_name)
```

The problem I'm having is that I want the option to save only one object and leave the other form fields empty. This sort of works. I can save just one field and therefore create only one object, but my form seems to be creating blank objects for the fields that are left empty. I want to stop these blank objects being created so I tried a few things out. I tried adding an else/if and a "pass" if the field is an empty string, but no luck.

For example.

```
def save(self):
        
        if quarterback_name == '':
            pass
        else:
            Quarterback.objects.create(name='quarterback_name')
```

I also tried

```
if quarterback_name == None:
            pass
        else:
            Quarterback.objects.create(name='quarterback_name')
```

Neither work. In fact, nothing gets created or saved at all.

Here are the relevant lines from views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":  
        form = PlayerForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = PlayerForm() 
    

    context = {'player_data': player_data,
               'form': form         
    }
    
    return render(request,'game/form.html', context)
```

I'm not quite sure how to fix this issue. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine several models into a single form.  **Don't do that!**  A form is meant to store a single model (or in complex cases, related models), but **not** several independent models.

The simplest solution would be to use a **[`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)** for each of your models, which would require modifying your template and view code.

Instead, I would recommend changing your *database schema*, to look something like this:

```
class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then populate your **`Position`** model via a **[`fixture`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures)**:

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.position",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "name": "Quarterback"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.position",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "name": "Runningback"
    }
  }
  ....
]
```

Then in your new form, you can use a **[`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)**:

```
class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    position = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Position.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'
```